# Modifying Angular Contentful API response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, contentful

I have a contentful service like so..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createClient, Entry } from 'contentful';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


const CONFIG = {
   space: '<spaceid>',
   accessToken: '<accesstoken>',

   contentTypeIds: {
      programItems: 'programItem'
   }
};

@Injectable()
export class ContentfulService {
private cdaClient = createClient({
    space: CONFIG.space,
    accessToken: CONFIG.accessToken
});

public weekNumber = new BehaviorSubject<any>(1);

constructor() { }
// Get all the program items
getProgramItems(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
   return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
     content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.programItems
   }, query))
   .then(res => res.items);
}

}
```

but I only want to bring in the programItems sys.ids in the contentful documentation.. you can modify api calls and return only certain values like this [modify api calls](https://www.contentful.com/r/knowledgebase/modifying-api-responses/)

`https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/<space_id>/entries/
    ?select=fields.productName,fields.price
    &content_type=<content_type_id>`

but Im not sure how I would implement the same thing, the way they do angular calls.. I could just do a http request but I would prefer to keep it the same way as I have done above

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a `select` property to your `getEntries` call.

```
// Get all the program items
getProgramItems(query?: object): Promise<Entry<any>[]> {
   return this.cdaClient.getEntries(Object.assign({
     content_type: CONFIG.contentTypeIds.programItems,
     select: 'sys.id'
   }, query))
   .then(res => res.items);
}
```

You can read the full documentation, including javascript snippets, here: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/reference/search-parameters/select-operator/query-entries/console/js